# DB design abbreviations

Tags: database

I know PK means primary key and FK means foreign key, but

what do "rK" (in section 3) and "PF" (in sections 3, 4, 6, 7, and 8) mean on this page?
http://www.databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_data_modelling/index.htm

And what does "FF" mean (in the Customer_Addresses table) on this page?
 -I'm new so it would only let me put in one hyperlink, so copy/paste this to go to the page I'm asking about:

databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_db_schema/tutorial_slide_7.htm

Thanks.

Edit: also, I understand the concepts of primary keys and foreign keys, but what are these other ones used for?

Answer (score 2):

It's the dude's own little annotation system for his diagrams.  It's not like you need to use them.  He defines them here:

http://www.databaseanswers.org/tutorial4_db_schema/tutorial_slide_5.htm

The weird-looking ones, "rK" and "FF", are just rendering issues: they're supposed to be FK and PF respectively.

The site is more than a little inconsistent from a design perspective... he's obviously not using any data modeling skills in the construction of the site.

Answer (score 1):

PF probably means the column is both a primary key and a foreign key (i.e., in a situation of 4th normal form, i.e., subtype/supertype modeling)

Answer (score 1):

rk = it looks like the letter F (upper case) couldn't fit into the circle. The circle appears to be smaller than the others. :)

[image]

Comment: yep, looks like a glitch in their rendering of the diagram